# C#: Get a user access token

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-oauth, facebook-access-token

I'm developing a desktop application in C#.

After visiting https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=123 the user logs in and the user access token is attached to the redirect uri. Its no problem, when the loginpage is displayed in a webbrowser control in my form, so i can extract the token from the url.

But this is not the way i want to get the token. My question is, is there a way to obtain the freshly created token **via an Graph API call**?

Because i want to display the login page in the user's standard browser and not in this embedded webbrowser. All my efforts to get the *user* access token have been resulted in getting the *app* access token, which is useless in this case.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// This is very raw, And Note it is a MVC3 solution, but it is in C# and I hope it helps.
// It is basically a C# version of the PHP example on FB for 'Server Side Flow' 
 // I have been at it for a while and had to go through some pain 
// Please note the bug I read about that states the redirect_uri must be the same for both //requests
// Also read that someone had an issue if the redirect_uri did not end in '/'
// Post back if you hae any ?s as I am just starting this project and am going to try and //incorporate the C# FaceBook SDK

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        // LoginWithFaceBook
        // First Contact with FB - oauth?client_id ... redirect_uri = /Account/FacebookLinker 
        // according to a bug files on FB redirect_uri MUST BE SAME FOR both trips ( to get the 'code' then exchange the code for 'access_token'
        public ActionResult ConnectFaceBookAccount()
        {
            string APP_ID = HttpContext.Application["FacebookAppId"].ToString();
            string redirect_uri = HttpContext.Application["FacebookOAuthRedirect"].ToString();
            string state = HttpContext.Application["state_guid"].ToString();
            // in this View I simply link to this URL
            ViewBag.FaceBookOAuthUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + APP_ID + "&redirect_uri="+redirect_uri+"&state=" + state+"&display=popup";


            return View();
        }

        // Account/FacebookLinker
        //  redirect_uri for both getting 'code' and exchanging for 'access_token'
        public ActionResult FacebookLinker()
        {
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Account/LogOn");
            }
            // Per FB DOC, Make sure 'state' var returned is same one you sent to reduce chance of Cross Site Forgery
            if (Request.QueryString["state"].ToString() == HttpContext.Application["state_guid"].ToString())
            {
                try
                {

                    string FBcode = Request.QueryString["code"].ToString();
                    string APP_ID = HttpContext.Application["FacebookAppId"].ToString();
                    string APP_SECRET = HttpContext.Application["FacebookAppSecret"].ToString();
                    string redirect_uri = HttpContext.Application["FacebookOAuthRedirect"].ToString();


                  string FBAccessUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + APP_ID + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri + "&client_secret=" + APP_SECRET + "&code=" + FBcode;


                string accessToken = null;
                // Send the request to exchange the code for access_token
                var accessTokenRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(FBAccessUrl);
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) accessTokenRequest.GetResponse();

                 // handle response from FB 
                 // this will not be a url with params like the first request to get the 'code'
                Encoding rEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(),rEncoding))
                {
                    // parse the response to get the value of the 'access_token'
                    accessToken = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(sr.ReadToEnd()).Get("access_token"); 
                }
                    //TODO
                    // Add to the accessToken for the Logged in User.Identity to a FBUSERS Model
                    // WHen someone Logs in Check to see if they are also in FB
                    // ON Login Page add option to login with FaceBook


                  return View();

                }
                catch (Exception exp)
                {
                    // try to get token failed

                }
            }
            else
            {
                 // state var form FB did not match state var sent

            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: How to get "code" and "state_guid". i also want to generate user_access_token

Answer (score 0):

I think this is achievable via URL protocol handlers;

1. Create a custom URL protocol handler ([MSDN: Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914.aspx))
2. Create a facebook page that passes user access token to your url handler (ex.  `myfbapp://accesstoken/{token}`)
3. Set oauth `redirect_uri` to your facebook page
4. Parse access token in your application